# Open CTI Call Centers vs. Lightning utility bar component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, servicecloud, opencti, twilio, utility-bar

A client needs to have voice capabilities in Lightning (incoming, outgoing calls and call recording), and I wanted to use the [Lightning Open CTI Demo](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Open_CTI) as a starting block.  After numerous attempts to get it working (see [here](https://moometric.com/integrations/sf/salesforce-open-cti-lightning-with-twilio-tutorial/) and [here](http://akashsenger.com/twiliosalesforce-integration/) for tutorials), I'm considering using a custom Lightning component that does all the Twilio calling functionality without using Call Centers / Open CTI at all.

**My question:** Is there any disadvantage to skipping call centers and just having a persistent Custom Lightning Component utility bar item that handles all the calling itself?  Will I be missing out on key Service Cloud functionality down the line?

It looks like the demo above was created before Lightning components themselves could be put into the Utility bar.

Answer (score 1):

Main disadvantage here is configurations that you need to configure record pages/layouts for each of profile while Call Centers/Open CTI gives ability to setup it once in utility bar. 
Also Open CTI enabled and user added in callcenter makes phone fields clickable and Call could be performed by clicking on that field.

If you just use component designed to work with Open CTI without enabling it for user -> you may find it non functional at all.

Comment: This was helpful - I didn't know about the clickable phone fields auto-performing calls on the Open CTI component